# Correctly formatting a PYTHONPATH in my .bash_profile

Tags: bash, pythonpath

I would like to add a `PYTHONPATH` to my .bash_profile but would like to check I'm doing this the correct way.  My `.bash_profile` (without a `PYTHONPATH`) looks like:

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:/home/user/condor/bin:/home/user/merlin/bin

export PATH
```

The path I would like to add to my PYTHONPATH is:

```
/home/user/merlin/bin/strats/
```

Therefore would my updated .bash_profile (with PYTHONPATH) looks like:

```
    # .bash_profile

    # Get the aliases and functions
    if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
            . ~/.bashrc
    fi

    # User specific environment and startup programs

    PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:/home/user/condor/bin:/home/user/merlin/bin

    export PATH

    export PYTHONPATH=/home/user/merlin/bin/strats/
```

How can I correctly format this?

Comment: Well.. .bash_profile is the place to configure any environment variable you want to have in your interactive shells.If this is what you want and your python programs are correctly importing modules from that directory, I would say all is OK. The only catch here is if there's already a PYTHONPATH variable inherited by system wide settings (i.e: /etc/environment, /etc/profile, /etc/profile.d/ or /etc/bash.bashrc). If this is the case, you'll be overwriting whatever was set.

Comment: Did you have the chance to test? If the answer helped you solve the issue, please accept it or comment it so it can be further enhanced.

Answer (score 3):

If it's your wish to be the sole owner and decision maker regarding `PYTHONPTAH` environment variable content on your interactive login shells, you're doing it right:

**~/.bash_profile** or **~/.profile**

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/user/merlin/bin/strats/
```

If you'd like to inherit any system-wide setting for `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, then you should:

**~/.bash_profile** or **~/.profile**

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/user/merlin/bin/strats/
```

Be aware that if you're working in a system where you can launch new terminals without logging in (i.e: launching a new `xterm` on your linux desktop), or in case you need that specific environment variable to run a script via cron, `.bash_profile` won't be executed and therefore the environment variable won't be available to that script.

As discussed in this answer comments, you can choose to use the `./~profile` file instead of `~/.bash_profile` to have additional compatibility with other shells.

Some folks simply add all environment configuration in `~/.bashrc`. Since your `.bash_profile` template call  `~/.bashrc`, you'd end up having those environment variables available in interactive login and non-login shells.

For scripts that run via cron, you should directly source the file where you have your environment configuration on the script itself or on the cron line because that won't be done automatically for you (crontab launches non-interactive shells to run the scripts and these are not affected by `~/.bashrc`,  `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`).

Comment: better to use ~/.profile and no ~/.bash_profile (instead of setting in ~/.bashrc), eg. on ubuntu 18, so environment variables are set just once at login and not every time you open a shell

Comment: @jenesaisquoi `.bash_profile` is sourced (by `bash`) under the same circumstances `.profile` is. If `.bash_profile` exists, it is used *instead* of `.profile` by `bash`.

Comment: @chepner .profile is sourced on login to ubuntu 18 but .bash_profile isn't

Comment: right, about .bash_profile being sourced instead of .profile and that's why I was saying its better to have only the .profile as it is more standard, probably works for most window managers

Comment: AFAIK, for interactive login shells, bash will source `~/.bash_profile` first (except for the system wide /etc/profile). Only if it doesn't find `~/.bash_profile` will it source `~/.bash_login` and if it doesn't find it either then it will go after `~/.profile`. The only way bash sources `~/.profile` first instead of `~/.bash_profile` is when bash is invoked with the `sh` command as a way to mimic the old `sh` behavior.

Comment: the problem with ~/.bash_profile is when it doesn't get sourced when the window manager starts up, eg. gnome w/ ubuntu 18.  Then when you start apps without launching them from a login shell they won't know about your environment settings

Comment: Yeah, don't really use ubuntu but it's good for everyone else who does to know that caveat :)