# Ubuntu Virtualbox: PYTHONPATH gone after restart

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, pythonpath

I use ubuntu 20.04 on virtualbox and set the python path with the given command

`export PYTHONPATH="/path/to/local/folder/"`

where my source files for modules I want to load are located.
But everytime I reboot the VM, the python path is reset, echo $PYTHONPATH does not return anything. I hope someone could help me with this issue as I'm really new to ubuntu.

Edit: I work in a conda virtual environment and want to set the path there

Comment: If you're using bash shell, you can edit your `$HOME/.bash_profile` file to include your export. And it will be set automatically every time you login. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56860389/362792

Comment: Thank you! That's really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a ServerFault question than a StackOverflow question, but regardless..

To declare a permanent environment variable, do one of the following:

- Set it for just you and your sessions in your bash profile with `echo 'export PYTHONPATH="/path/to/local/folder/"' >> ~/.profile`
- Set it system-wide in profile.d with `echo 'export PYTHONPATH="/path/to/local/folder"' >> /etc/profile.d/pythonpath.sh && chmod 755 /etc/profile.d/pythonpath.sh`

For the second one you'll need sudo/root permissions, and it will take effect for all users on the host. Just depends on how you want to do it and how you want things to work.

EDIT: Including reference material as well: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Comment: Your first sentence is reason for voting to close the question as it is off topic. **Not all questions can or should be answered here.** Do not answer off topic questions. [answer]

Comment: I'd argue that moving it is better, but the point remains.

Comment: Oh sorry I did not know about that. Still, thank you for your answer. It helped me a lot...